# gnuplot basic graphing issues

Tags: linux, unix, gnuplot

I have been trying to graph my data set using GNUPLOT, but so far have been uneventful in producing a successful graph. My input file consists of data that looks like the following..

## x y

12 10.1.1.5

56 10.2.3.1

12 10.4.1.4

Where everything in the X column is the amount of times the IP address in the Y column has been accessed in an hours time frame.
I would like for the y column that has the IP addresses to be labels, and the X column to be the data that I want to represent.
I really appreciate any help that anyone could provide, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple:

```
 plot 'yourdatafile' u 1:xtic(2)
```

should do the trick.